# Does AngularJS rendering of a partial block the download of other templates?

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

So I'm running into an issue on Internet Explorer(works on all other browsers) where it seems like a directive's HTML is taking 20+ seconds to retrieve from the server.  The page is set up like this:

```
<div class="groups-page">
    ...
    <test-directive></test-directive>
    <div class="groups">
        <h1 ng-repeat="x in records">{{x}}</h1>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Records is array with about 5000 items.  Looking at the networks tab, the groups-page HTML is loaded in several ms.  Now since we have 5000 records, I'm assuming it takes a lot of time to render.  As a result of this, I see that the test-directive HTML just sits there in the network tab and finally is "downloaded" after 20 seconds.  Am I right in saying that I need to limit the amount of data bindings here and that's what is causing the test-directive HTML to take so long to download?  If I set a limitTo on the ng-repeat, it makes it much faster the more I limit it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely due to the sheer amount of work Angular has to do to generate and bind 5,000 copies of your template.  What you will see in the browser is that your client downloads the data, and then as soon as it is loaded, it hangs for a while while it generates the necessary HTML to add to the DOM.  Once it finishes, the page becomes responsive again and the elements are drawn on the screen.  At very large amounts of data, your browser starts to slow down with the number of DOM elements it is keeping track of, even after it is painted.

You have several options to mitigate this, including the following:

1. Reduce the number of data-bindings in your template
2. Page your data so that you aren't showing so many at a time
3. Use "infinite scrolling" (performance gets worse as items are added to the DOM while you scroll)
4. Look into implementing virtual scrolling for your list (essentially having the DOM only render a portion of the actual results that shifts as you scroll).

I ran into the same issue myself, and ultimately went with option 4.  It is probably the most work out of options above, but the solution is handling an array of 200,000 items quite smoothly.  If you don't want to create your own virtual scroll, there are a handful of open source implementations out there now that are worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  What I don't understand is why this only happens in IE11.  Is that browser just not optimized?  Also, is my original assumption correct?  The work that Angular has to do is blocking the other template from downloading until it's done rendering?

Comment: All of the HTML generation is done in the UI thread, and from past experience, IE's JavaScript engine is much slower than Chrome and other browsers, so you will see this issue sooner in IE than you would in other browsers, but it can affect all of them.  I'm not sure what "other templates" you are referring to.  Are you seeing "test-directive" not start in the network pane until 20 seconds later?

Comment: The test-directive partial is taking 20 seconds to download and it's essentially just an input box.  If I reduce the amount of records, the download time significantly decreases.

Comment: When you mouse over the "Waterfall" column for the traffic for your template, where is the 20 seconds being spent?  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#timing-explanation

Comment: This only happens on IE11 but it is stuck on the "Content Downloading" for 20s